# Angular 9 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, observable, typescript-typings

I am using async pipe in my template for an Observable:

```
applicants$: Observable<UserProfile[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.applicants$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRootUserProfileState.getUserProfiles)
    ) as Observable<UserProfile[]>;
}
```

Here is UserProfile.ts interface:

```
import { Role } from './role/role';
import { Country } from './Country';

export interface UserProfile {
  id?: number;
  fullName?: string;
  roles?: Role[];
  windowsAccount?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  email?: string;
  managerName?: string;
  managerId?: number;
  managerEmail?: string;
  companyId?: number;
  companyName?: string;
  countryId?: number;
  country?: Country;
  countryName?: string;
}
```

And here is the userProfile.service

```
  getUserProfiles(): Observable<UserProfile[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserProfile[]>(
      this.baseUrl + 'userprofiles/getuserprofiles'
    );
  }
```

In the template I've used ngFor to iterate through the Observable with an async pipe:

```
<mat-form-field
  fxFlex="22"
  appearance="outline"
  *ngIf="applicants$ | async as applicants"
>
  <mat-label>Applicant</mat-label>
  <mat-icon matPrefix>person</mat-icon>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Applicant"
    name="applicant"
    [(ngModel)]="this.searchPurchaseOrder.applicantId"
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let ap of applicants" [value]="ap.id">
      ap.fullName
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, here is the error I am getting:
[image]

Here is the data shape from the store. It is being populated, so there is no problem there:
[image]

Comment: Can you check that your store has that data? Also,  console.log() to see the format of that data

Comment: I have added the data snip at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use the keyvalue pipe to loop through your object as if it were an array.

https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

```
<div *ngFor="let applicant of applicants | keyvalue">
  {{applicant.key}}:{{applicant.value}}
</div>
```

This can work with the async pipe too, e.g:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (object$ | async) | keyvalue">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to use ngFor to loop through an object (Which is not possible). If you can post a preview of the response from the network tab it would be helpful to get a better idea about the matter.

Comment: The response preview data is added at the end.

Comment: Try Using <mat-option *ngFor="let ap of applicants$ | async" [value]="ap.id">.

Comment: Try removing the async pipe in ngIf '*ngIf="applicants$"' and use the async pipe on the ng for like I suggested earlier and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Matt Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627160/matt-saunders)' answer this change to the template has worked for my case:

```
<mat-form-field
  fxFlex="22"
  appearance="outline"
  *ngIf="this.applicants$ | async | keyvalue as applicants">
  <mat-label>Applicant</mat-label>
  <mat-icon matPrefix>person</mat-icon>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Applicant"
    name="applicant"
    [(ngModel)]="this.searchPurchaseOrder.applicantId">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let applicant of applicants"
      [value]="applicant.value.id">
      {{ applicant.value.fullName }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pipe with the alias also: `let ap of applicants | async`.

Comment: Async pipe has already been applied beforehand. If I use it as you said I get this error: ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0):

Well if you getting the data from backend..... Like node Mongo then follow this approach

```js
res.status().json({ data: [yourdata] })
```

Now you don't need to do anything.

Happy codding.